# Can someone explain to me why this code returns 1

Tags: javascript, object

Why this code returns 1, the method toString even not called anywhere, + operator should turn its operand to a number but i tried this and returned NaN

```
+{} // NaN
+{a: 2} //NaN
```

so why this code returns 1 ????

```
+({x:+null , y : +'001' , toString : function(){return this.x+this.y;}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an expression uses a non-number value in a way that needs it to be a number, the value is first converted to its primitive value equivalent. Then, the primitive value is coerced to a number.

The steps taken by a JavaScript interpreter are as follows:

1. Call `valueOf` and convert it to a number, if possible.
2. Call `toString`, and if the return value is primitive, convert it to a number, if possible.
3. Throw `TypeError`.

In your case, since you use the unary `+` operator with a non-number object, and the unary `+` operator is only defined for numbers, these steps are taken. Your object does not have a `valueOf`, but it does have a `toString` method, so the return vaule of `toString`, coerced to a number, is used to evaluate the expression.

Kyle Simpson's excellent [You Don't Know JS: Types & Grammar](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html) has more on type coercion, if you would like to explore further.

Comment: This is really what i am missing , so toString is called here by js engine and its value coerced to number. clear now

Answer (score 2):

> +({x:+null , y : +'001' , toString : function(){return this.x+this.y;}})

You are overloading `toString` which function returns `(+null+'001')`

+null coerces null to 0;

+'001' coerces the string to 1

you are returning 1 from toString.

In the previous cases, the result of non a overloaded toString method of an object literal is `"[object Object]"` which coerced to a number gives NaN.

The only thing that matters here is what toString, overloaded or not, returns.

Comment: my question is about toString here , why it even returns 1 and it was not even called anywhere? @mpm

Comment: Because that's how implicit type coercion is implemented in javascript. if a method toString() exists on a object, javascript will use it to coerce the object to a primitive type (string,number,...), as defined in the Ecmascript specification. The default implementation of Object#toString() returns `"[object Object]"`